# How to turn off auto-formatting in IntelliJ 14 for play routing files?

Tags: scala, playframework, intellij-14

Everytime I press return to enter a new route into the file it auto-reformats the entire file which I do not want.  I cannot find the setting to turn off the auto-formatting, is there one?

Comment: That is a very nice question. I have to add that in my case it is not only formatting all the time the code and messing with git, but it is behaving in a unpredictable manner. Some times it is replacing the tabs with spaces and sometimes it is replacing the spaces with tabs. For me this is a serious bug and I would rather it did not auto-format at all than what it is currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its possible right now, there are a number of issues related to this (especially for scala formatting) eg. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56995 or https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6702.

Currently I'm on Intellij 14 and formatting toggle with `'@formatter:off'`  works only for Java source and doesn't work for configs, Scala etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to file my discontent there.